# norm of positive semi-definite complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, adjoint-operators

Suppose $0\neq X_n\in \mathbb{M}_{k(n)}(\mathbb{C})$,if $\lim_{n \to \infty}tr(X_n^*X_n)=0$,can we conclude that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\|X_n^*X_n\|=0$,where $tr$ is the standard trace on complex matrix,$\|·\|$ is the norm of matrix.

My thought: the eigenvalues of $X_n^*X_n$ is non-negative,$ tr(X_n^*X_n) $ is equal to the sum of non-negative eigenvalues,so each non-negative eigenvalue is small enough,the norm of $X_n^*X_n$ is equal to the product of eigenvalues,so it tends to zero.Is my idea correct?

Comment: Is there a bound on $k(n)$?

Comment: What norm are you using ? If it is the Frobenius norm then it is equal to the highest eigenvalue in norm, so your argument proves that it converges to zero.

Comment: What do you mean by the "matrix norm"? Is it the operator norm??

Comment: Can we define the norm of $A$ as the product of eigenvalues of $A$ ?@P. Quinton

Comment: @Berci,$\mathbb{M}_{k(n)}(\mathbb{C})$ is finite dimensional matrix.

Comment: @P. Quinton,all the norms are equivalent in finite dimensional space.If the norm is the operator norm,the answer is not true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The matrices $X_n^*X_n$ are positive, so their eigenvalues are nonnegative. The trace is sum of the eigenvalues and the norm (if you are using the operator norm, you don't say) is the greatest eigenvalue. So you always have 
$$
\|X_n^*X_n\|\leq\operatorname{Tr}(X_n^*X_n). 
$$
If you allow an arbitrary norm, the answer is no. For instance, take the norm(s) to be 
$$
\|A\|_n=\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^n|A_{kj}|^2\right)^{1/2}.$$
Now put $X_n=n^{-5/4}E_n$, where $E_n$ is the $n\times n$ matrix with all entries equal to $1$. It is easy to check that $E_n^2=nE_n$, and that $E_n$ is positive. Now
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(X_n^*X_n)=n^{-5/2}\operatorname{Tr}(E_n^2)=n^{-1/2}\to0.
$$
Meanwhile, $|X_n^*X_n|=X_n^*X_n$, and 
\begin{align}
\|X_n^*X_n\|_n&=n^{-5/2}\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^nn^2\right)^{1/2}
=n^{-5/2}nn^{3/2}=1.
\end{align}

Comment: I am a little comfusing.all norms are equivalent in finite dimensional case.If we take other norms,why the answer is not true?

Comment: It is a common mistake to use a general phrase without looking at the context. Here, it is true that "all norms are equivalent in **a** finite-dimensional space". But, between different finite-dimensional spaces, like $M_2(\mathbb C)$ and $M_3(\mathbb C)$, the phrase doesn't even make sense.

Comment: oh,I see.Thanks!

Comment: The operator norm $$\|A\|=\sup\{(x^*A^*Ax)^{1/2}:\ x^*x=1\} $$ is precisely the greatest singular value of $A $.